# Does Go fmt indent automatically?

Tags: unix, go, terminal

When I do `fmt.Printf("...\n")` it doesn't move the cursor to the 0th column and the next line is therefore indented:

```
13
  13
    13
      13
        13
          13
            113 ('q')
```

Here is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "unicode"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal"
)

func main() {
    oldState, err := terminal.MakeRaw(0)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer terminal.Restore(0, oldState)

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    var c rune
    for err == nil {
        if c == 'q' {
            break
        }

        c, _, err = reader.ReadRune()

        if unicode.IsControl(c) {
            fmt.Printf("%d\n", c)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("%d ('%c')\n", c, c)
        }
    }

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: You're putting the terminal in raw mode, doesn't that require a carriage return to put the cursor at the start of the line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Comment: You're putting the terminal in raw mode, doesn't that require a
>   carriage return to put the cursor at the start of the line? – JimB

---

For example,

`terminal.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "unicode"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh/terminal"
)

func main() {
    oldState, err := terminal.MakeRaw(0)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer terminal.Restore(0, oldState)

    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)

    var c rune
    for err == nil {
        if c == 'q' {
            break
        }

        c, _, err = reader.ReadRune()

        if unicode.IsControl(c) {
            fmt.Printf("%d\r\n", c)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("%d ('%c')\r\n", c, c)
        }
    }

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go run terminal.go
13
13
13
13
13
113 ('q')
$
```